# Multiple Transactions in mysql for Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, transactions, sequelize.js

I'm using node's driver for mysql and need to execute 'n' number of transactions one after the other and not simultaneously.

I've tried using a for/forEach loop but the transactions seem to happen concurrently and that causes my api to crash.Here's the error :-

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

One single transactions seems to work just fine.

Each transaction has 4 queries, req.body is an array of objects:-

```
router.post('/production/add', (req, res) => {
    for (const obj of req.body) {
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;

                const query1 = `select qty from production where prc_id = ${obj.prc_id}`;
                console.log(query1);
                connection.query(query1, function (error, result1, fields) {
                    if (error) {
                        return connection.rollback(function () {
                            res.status(400).send({ query: 1, message: error.sqlMessage, code: error.code, errno: error.errno });
                            return;
                        });
                    }
                    const new_prod_qty = result1[0].qty - obj.auth_prod_qty;
                    const query2 = new_prod_qty > 0 ? `update production set qty = ${new_prod_qty} where prc_id = ${obj.prc_id}` : `delete from production where prc_id = ${obj.prc_id}`;
                    console.log(query2);
                    connection.query(query2, function (error, results2, fields) {
                        if (error) {
                            return connection.rollback(function () {
                                res.status(400).send({ message: error.sqlMessage, code: error.code, errno: error.errno });
                                return;
                            });
                        }
                        const query3 = `update prc set auth_prod_qty = ${obj.auth_prod_qty} where prc_id = ${obj.prc_id}`;
                        console.log(query3);
                        connection.query(query3, function (error, results3, fields) {
                            if (error) {
                                return connection.rollback(function () {
                                    res.status(400).send({ message: error.sqlMessage, code: error.code, errno: error.errno });
                                    return;
                                });
                            }
                            const query4 = "select * from store";
                            connection.query(query4, function (error, results3, fields) {
                                if (error) {
                                    return connection.rollback(function () {
                                        res.status(400).send({ message: error.sqlMessage, code: error.code, errno: error.errno });
                                        return;
                                    });
                                }
                                connection.commit(function (err) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        return connection.rollback(function () {
                                            res.status(400).send({ message: error.sqlMessage, code: error.code, errno: error.errno });
                                            return;
                                        });
                                    }
                                    res.status(201).send(results2);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };
});
```

Based off some research Sequelize ORM seems to promisify transactions but however I'm hoping to use it as a last resort. Any sort of solution with or without Sequelize would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  It's generally best to *answer your own question* rather than update your question when you figure out the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `async / await` to run your txs sequentially.  How to do this?

Use [npm mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) in place of [npm mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). That gets you [promisified (awaitable) versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper) of the APIs when you `require('mysql2/promise')`. Plus, this is **much** more fun to program and debug than those miserable nested callbacks. Just don't forget the `await`s.

Use this basic outline for your code's data processing loop. Everything will go in order sequentially.  The way you create your pool is a little different; read the npm page.  This is *not debugged.*

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

router.post('/production/add', async (req, res) => {
  const connection = await pool.getConnection()

  for (const obj of req.body) {
    try {
      await connection.beginTransaction()
      const query1 = 'whatever'
      const result1 = await connection.query(query1)
      const query2 = 'something else'
      const result 2 = await connection.query(query2)
      /* etcetera etcetera */
      await connection.commit()
    } 
    catch (error) {
      await connection.rollback()
      pool.releaseConnection()
      res.status(400).send({ something })
    }
  }
  pool.releaseConnection()
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion, this is exactly what I was looking for as it works well with mysql too and just uses promise() method to upgrade a mysql connection to a promisified version of mysql2 connection! I've edited the question to include my implementation any critiques?

Answer (score 0):

mysql2/promise is exactly the package I was looking for, works with mysql and uses promise() method to upgrade mysql connection to a promise based mysql2 connection.

```
router.post('/stock/add', async (req, res) => {
    const connection = pool.getConnection(async function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            connection.release();
            res.status(400).send(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            for (const obj of req.body) {
                try {
                    await connection.promise().beginTransaction();
                    const [result1, fields1] = await connection.promise().query(query1)
                    const [result2, fields2] = await connection.promise().query(query2);
                    const [result3, fields3] = await connection.promise().query(query3);
                    const [result4, fields4] = await connection.promise().query(query4);
                    await connection.promise().commit();
                }
                catch (error) {
                    await connection.promise().rollback();
                    connection.release();
                    res.status(400).send(error);
                    return;
                }
            }
            res.status(200).send('Transaction Complete');
        }
    });
});
```